# Android Studio : Does not display test reports folder

Tags: android-studio, android-testing

I am using Android Studio 0.6.1 & build tools 19.1.
I have written some sample test & cases and ran connectedAndroidTest (InstrumentTest has been renamed to AndroidTest in the latest build tools).
The 'reports' folder & the index.html are created successfully, as I can view them from the file system. But the IDE does not display them in the 'build' folder, because of which I thought there was a problem with the test environment set up? which was not the case.

Does anybody know how to fix this??

Answer (score 0):

That is actually on purpose. The `/build` folder for example is hidden as well.

The reason for this is that its distracting the coding workflow.

If you like to see your test results open your project folder in your filemanager and navigate to the index.html you want to look at.
Then open the file in your browser and add a favourite.
After that you can reopen your tests directly in the browser.

So no need to actually acess it from intellij or android studio anyway.